# I am unable to install//download Hadoop with Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop

I am using Ubuntu in Virtualbox (both installed on Windows OS). I downloaded Hadoop to Windows (Downloads folder) in order to install it on Ubuntu. But I am unable to complete this task. I follow Hadoop installation steps from [here](https://thegeekadoxography.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/setting-up-hadoop-for-dummies-single-node-cluster-on-linux/).

I tried 2 options below and I received the following errors:

```
hduser@ubuntu14:/usr/local$ sudo cp ~/Downloads/hadoop2.7.1.tar.gz .
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop2.7.1.tar.gz’: No such file or directory
```

and:

```
hduser@ubuntu14:/usr/local$ wget http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz
Resolving mirrors.sonic.net (mirrors.sonic.net)... 69.12.162.27
Connecting to mirrors.sonic.net (mirrors.sonic.net)|69.12.162.27|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 210606807 (201M) [application/x-gzip]
hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz’ (Permission denied).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your errors are pretty intuitive here.

- Option 1 you tried:

You cannot copy from the machine **hosting** the VM to the VM unless you have [defined a shared folder](http://www.howtogeek.com/189974/how-to-share-your-computers-files-with-a-virtual-machine/), hence the `/home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop2.7.1.tar.gz not found` error.

- Option 2 you tried:

`Cannot write to hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz (Permission denied).` means you do not have the appropriate permissions in order to download this file.

You can try the same command in option 2 with `sudo` in order to fix this **or** download the hadoop `tar` file from ***within*** your VM and extract it for your first option.

Comment: Dimitris Jim, you are the Master! Thank you very much for your help. Adding "Sudo" resolved the issue: sudo wget http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Add `sudo`at the beginning of the command to solve the Permission problem. It allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user.